# No pagenumbers in moderncv

Tags: page-numbering, moderncv

I am using texlive (2012) with moderncv (1.5.1). Since a certain update pagenumbers have disappeared for previously working examples. Yes i have more than one page and `\nopagenumbers{}` is commented. Am i missing something?

Take e.g. `template.tex` from [CTAN Examples](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples) which will not yield any pagenumbers even though the precompiled examples clearly have them.

**Update**:
Using Gonzalo Medina's example of the comments here is the output of `*File List*` from `.log` using `TeXShop 3.18`, `Texlive 2013` and `moderncv 1.5.1`. Still not getting any page numbers (after multiple runs):

```
 *File List*
moderncv.cls    2013/04/29 v1.5.1 modern curriculum vitae and letter document c
lass
  size11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
 lmodern.sty    2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
fancyhdr.sty    
tweaklist.sty    
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  xparse.sty    2013/03/12 v4467 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2013/03/14 v4469 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
 l3names.sty    2012/12/07 v4346 L3 Namespace for primitives
l3bootstrap.sty    2013/01/08 v4420 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
l3basics.sty    2013/01/10 v4428 L3 Basic definitions
 l3expan.sty    2013/02/03 v4458 L3 Argument expansion
    l3tl.sty    2013/01/08 v4415 L3 Token lists
   l3seq.sty    2013/01/12 v4434 L3 Sequences and stacks
   l3int.sty    2013/01/13 v4444 L3 Integers
 l3quark.sty    2012/11/04 v4268 L3 Quarks
   l3prg.sty    2013/02/13 v4459 L3 Control structures
 l3clist.sty    2013/01/08 v4414 L3 Comma separated lists
 l3token.sty    2013/01/10 v4428 L3 Experimental token manipulation
  l3prop.sty    2013/01/09 v4423 L3 Property lists
   l3msg.sty    2013/01/08 v4412 L3 Messages
  l3file.sty    2013/01/14 v4446 L3 File and I/O operations
  l3skip.sty    2013/01/13 v4444 L3 Dimensions and skips
  l3keys.sty    2013/02/24 v4461 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
    l3fp.sty    2013/01/19 v4449 L3 Floating points
   l3box.sty    2013/01/08 v4411 L3 Experimental boxes
l3coffins.sty    2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Coffin code layer
 l3color.sty    2012/08/29 v4156 L3 Experimental color support
l3luatex.sty    2012/08/03 v4049 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
l3candidates.sty    2013/03/14 v4468 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
microtype.sty    2013/05/23 v2.5a Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
microtype-pdftex.def    2013/05/23 v2.5a Definitions specific to pdftex (RS)
microtype.cfg    2013/05/23 v2.5a microtype main configuration file (RS)
moderncvcollection.sty    2013/04/29 v1.5.1 moderncv collections
moderncvcompatibility.sty    2013/04/29 v1.5.1 modern curriculum vitae and lett
er compatibility patches
moderncvstylecasual.sty    2013/04/29 v1.5.1 modern curriculum vitae and letter
 style scheme: casual
moderncvstyleclassic.sty    2013/04/29 v1.5.1 modern curriculum vitae and lette
r style scheme: classic
moderncviconsmarvosym.sty    2013/04/29 v1.5.1 modern curriculum vitae and lett
er icons: marvosym
    tikz.sty    2012/08/29 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.100)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/11/07 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.25)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2012/03/30 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.38)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2012/08/27 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.22)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
    umvs.fd
moderncviconsawesome.sty    2013/04/29 v1.5.1 modern curriculum vitae and lette
r icons: awesome
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
   puenc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
   t1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
  mt-cmr.cfg    2013/05/19 v2.2 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman (
RS)
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
Ohne-Titel.out
Ohne-Titel.out
  ot1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
  omllmm.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omslmsy.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omxlmex.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 ***********
```

Comment: Hmmmm... using that exact file, I get page numbers at the bottom right corner with TeX Live2013 and moderncv v1.5.1.

Comment: I'll add the "me too" comment since I just produced a CV using moderncv v 1.5.1 and TeXLive 2012.  Page numbers appeared appropriately.

Comment: moderncv v1.5.1 isn't part of TeXLive 2012 so you have to insure that it's being used.  It's not the recommended way, but I added the moderncv package as a subdir of the CV I was working on.  My makefile set some environment variables to insure pdflatex looked at my moderncv subdir first for classes and styles.  Are you sure you're using v1.5.1?

Comment: Yes. I also just updated to `TeXLive 2013` and still do not get any pagenumbers with moderncv 1.5.1. Now when i downgrade moderncv to `1.4.0` they suddenly do appear. Clueless.

Comment: Take this simple document *exactly* as it is: `\documentclass{moderncv}
\listfiles
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\name{John}{Doe}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  
\clearpage
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  
\end{document}` and compile it. Do you get page numbers? If not, please open the `.log` file, search for the section `*File List*` and add the content of this section to your question.

Comment: Have you compiled your resume twice? Page numbers require two compilations in order to get determine the total number of pages during the first one.

Comment: That's true. But even so the problem persists. I have added the requested `.log` output to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i wanted to let you know that i solved it.
I dumped my `texmf-local` (even though i did not find anything related to moderncv), refreshed my tex distribution `sudo mktexlsr` and finally the pagenumbers became visible - Shazam.

Comment: I have the same problems. Some other ideas what might work? Problem did only occur because I reinstalled my text distribution...

Comment: Okay, I still don't know what's the problem, but that solution did work: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207374/page-numbers-with-moderncv-package-on-mactex-2014-dont-show